# How can I see my excluded folders in PhpStorm 2020.3?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I've changed the project folder and marked it as Excluded. Later I need to re-show my excluded folders but I don't know how to show it again. Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the "gear" icon on the Project View panel (or right click on the toolwindow title) to bring the toolwindow options. There is an option just for that:

[image]

*(the `data` and `downloads` are excluded folders)*

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Just click project files in Project Window.
There is 'cancel excluded' button.

[image]